# Transform element attributes into sub-elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some xml fragments that looks like this

```
<an_element1 attribute1="some value" attribute2="other value" ... attributeN="N value">
<an_element2 attribute1="some value" attribute2="other value" ... attributeN="N value">
...
```

I need to transform it in something like this:

```
<an_element1>
<attribute1>some value</attribute1>
<atttibute2>other value</attribute2>
...
<attributeN>N value</attributeN>
</an_element1>
<an_element2>
<attribute1>some value</attribute1>
<atttibute2>other value</attribute2>
...
<attributeN>N value</attributeN>
</an_element2>
...
```

I have already succesfully tried some examples found in other answers, but I wanted to know if there is a sort of generic approach to this problem that can be summarized like this:

for each element named an_element create a sub-element for each of its attributes each containing their respective values.

Since the repeating elements may contain duplicated values (two an_element items with identical values for all their attributes) I wanted to know if it is possible to filter only unique elements.

If the filter is possible it's better to apply it before or after the transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for each element named an_element create a sub-element for each of its attributes each containing their respective values.

The following stylesheet converts all attributes into like-named elements.  Elements generated from attributes will precede elements copied from the child elements in the source.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XST/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you only want to do this for elements with a particular name you need something more like

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XST/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="an_element/@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which would convert

```
<an_element foo="bar"/>
```

into

```
<an_element>
  <foo>bar</foo>
</an_element>
```

but would leave `<another_element attr="whatever"/>` unchanged.

Comment: Thanks, It almost worked... But I get empty sub-elements (no original attribute values).

Comment: Sorry I tried it before the answer was completed. Probably a cut and paste error.

Comment: @sblandin yes, I made a mistake in my first version of the `@*` template.  If the answer now works for you it's good manners to _accept_ it using the tick mark to the left.  Building a track record of accepting good answers will encourage more people to help you with your future questions.

Comment: Accepted. But I still wonder if it is possible to get an unique list of elements. Should I need to post another question?

Comment: @sblandin I think it would make more sense to ask the second part as a separate question, the two parts (attributes to elements and de-duplication) are pretty much orthogonal.